# I want to get the value of A table JOIN B table, But I get SQLGrammarException:could not extract resultset

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I use PostGreSQL DB, It's have two table:

`1.UserHeader
  (
   userid integer primary key default nextval('userheader_seq'),
   username character varying(20) NOT NULL
  )
2.TestTable
 (
  testid integer NOT NULL,
  testnam character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_testtable PRIMARY KEY (testid)
 )`

My two entity:

```
@Entity
public class UserHeader implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "userHeader_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "userHeader_seq", sequenceName = "userHeader_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Integer userID;
private String userName = "";

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<TestTable> testTables;

public List<TestTable> getTestTable() {
    return testTables;
}

public void setTestTable(List<TestTable> testTables) {
    this.testTables = testTables;
}


public Integer getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
public class TestTable implements Serializable {
@Id
private Integer testID;
private String testNam;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private UserHeader userHeader;

public UserHeader getUserHeader() {
    return userHeader;
}

public void setUserHeader(UserHeader userHeader) {
    this.userHeader = userHeader;
}

public Integer getTestID() {
    return testID;
}

public void setTestID(Integer testID) {
    this.testID = testID;
}

public String getTestNam() {
    return testNam;
}

public void setTestNam(String testNam) {
    this.testNam = testNam;
}
```

}

I run it:

`Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from UserHeader u left join u.testTables t");
userHeaders = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();`

But I get Exception:
`org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

I run it:

`Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from UserHeader u left join u.testTables t");
userHeaders = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();`


But I get Exception:

`org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

Could someone tell me where this is a mistake?
My English is not good, please forgive me.

Comment: What do you think `u.testTables` is? **Hint**: It's not `TestTable`. Also, what are you *joining* on?

Comment: why not : `userHeaders = (List<UserHeader>) query.list();`

Comment: NB You have omitted "SELECT u " from your queries meaning they are now not valid JPQL. Perhaps you'd like to fix that

Comment: I try Add  "SELECT u " , but it's not work

Comment: I see no FOREIGN KEY in the TestTable table. Without a Foreign Key how do you expect to have a relation? You didn't get your JPA provider to create those tables did you?

Comment: I got it, Neil Stockton , thanks